# How to Union the same datasets very fast

Tags: sql-server

I have **one table** and I want see all columns from a particular year and all ID (also from different years) complete.

| ID | Salary | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2023 |
| 2 | 200 | 2022 |
| 3 | 30 | NULL |

It works with UNION, but I wonder whetever there are a better function. See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/hos_N0yM

Do someone know a better and more efficent method? I use it with 100std rows then it is not fast. Union seems not to be a fast method.

If i SET YEAR to 2023 then this should be the output

| ID | Salary | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2023 |
| 2 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | NULL |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if this is faster, `` ,see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/SR4nYl_T)

```
DECLARE @YEAR int = 2023

SELECT  s1.[ID]
      , CASE WHEN YEAR=@YEAR THEN s1.[Salary] END as Salary
      , CASE WHEN YEAR=@YEAR THEN s1.[YEAR] END as YEAR
FROM [dbo].[Salary] as s1
WHERE s1.[YEAR] = @YEAR OR (s1.[YEAR] <> @YEAR OR s1.[YEAR] is null)
```

But it seems that, without seeing an [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) this might also not have enough speed because the complete table needs to be fetched.

EDIT:

- **The WHERE-clause in above SQL statement can be deleted**. This is because, with this WHERE-clause, every record will be returned.
- But why is it still there?

In the original query (from OP) it says:

```
SELECT  s1.[ID]
      , s1.[Salary]
      , s1.[YEAR] 
FROM [dbo].[Salary] as s1
WHERE s1.[YEAR] = @YEAR

UNION ALL

SELECT  [ID]
      , NULL
      , NULL
FROM [dbo].[Salary] as sb
WHERE [YEAR] <> @YEAR OR [YEAR] is null
```

I replaced the `UNION ALL`, which results in combining both WHERE-clauses to `(s1.[YEAR] = @YEAR) OR ([YEAR] <> @YEAR OR [YEAR] is null)`

Within a minute of this post, I got a [comment from Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75844187/how-to-union-the-same-datasets-very-fast/75844234?noredirect=1#comment133782270_75844234) that the WHERE-clause is not needed.

Conclusion: The WHERE-clause is not needed, but I will leave it here to show future readers how you can convert a `UNION ALL` to an SQL statement with a WHERE-clause.  In this case there's just a bit extra gain because this WHERE clause can be deleted.

Comment: Its faster, almost douple fast. But the readability is low

Comment: @MartinSmith: I was still creating the answer, when I noticed there are only OR's in the WHERE-clause which makes the WHERE-clause not needed.

Comment: @Petersselorse: readability low ?  Is this because of the `CASE WHEN....END` or because of the WHERE-clause ?   The WHERE-clause can be deleted/ignored.

Comment: Yes i meant the content of the WHERE clause was hard to understand, but yes without it better

Comment: @Luuk, your code is faster, but why

Comment: Look at the execution plan of both statements. and compare them.   Welcome to the wonderful, and complex, world of query optimization 

Comment: I still don't get why you need the `WHERE` it isn't doing anything. ALL possible conditions are being included anyway. https://dbfiddle.uk/yQnT6pVi

Comment: @Charlieface: I edited my answer to explain the WHERE-clause, and to NOTE that, in this case, you can delete the WHERE-clause.

Comment: I really don't understand the point of it all. The code at the top is the best, just without the `WHERE`. There is no need for `UNION ALL` *or* the `WHERE`, just use `CASE` in the `SELECT`. https://dbfiddle.uk/ySiqQr8I

Comment: @Charlieface: Sorry I tried to explain why the WHERE-clause is there. But, because I am not a native English speaker, I am having troubles explaining it clearly.  Just the EDIT should make it clear that the WHERE-clause i not needed. And when your use it the optimizer will filter the use of it (in this case!).  Because when the two WHERE-clauses do not add-up to a complete result of the whole table, the WHERE-clause cannot/shouldnot be deleted.

Comment: `WHERE s1.[YEAR] = @YEAR` they are equal and therefore not null `OR (s1.[YEAR] <> @YEAR` they are unequal and therefore not null `OR s1.[YEAR] is null)` or the column is null. So all possible options are covered.